# proper regular expression to extract a specific number from long string

Tags: .net, nsregularexpression

input string: |1|!!!ABC|**9.56**!|x10e3/uL||0.1m1v0|||||XDS||202f914120247|01

need to extract: 9.56

Dim matchResult = Regex.Match(inputString, "|(\d+(.\d+)?)  !")
does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `\|(\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?)!\|`

```
using System;
    
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\|(\d{1,}(\.\d{1,})?)!\|";
        string input = @"|1|!!!ABC|9.56!|x10e3/uL||0.1m1v0|||||XDS||202f914120247|01";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        var m = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options)[0];
        var g = m.Groups[1];
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", g.Value);
    }
}
```